Bootnode return ip="invalid IP" udp=0 tcp=0 on local environment?
I'm learning and the process i found limitations with Ganache.
First with alternatives i have ?
Trying to create my own private block with geth i got this issue:
I try to create two nodes with bootnode, that's what i get :
INFO [07-28|20:54:53.303] New local node record                    seq=1,722,196,493,303 id=bd4d72b23948df21 ip="invalid IP" udp=0 tcp=0
Firewall checked, and gpt not helping anymore
[ALL]

PS ...anathan\block\boot> bootnode -nodekey boot.key -verbosity 9
-addr 192.168.1.102:30301 enode://13649e7feeb06fa******************421d10cf15d5799736cdae@192.168.1.102:0?discport=30301 Note: you're using cmd/bootnode, a developer tool. We recommend using
a regular node as bootstrap node for production deployments. INFO
[07-28|21:03:07.188] New local node record
seq=1,722,196,987,183 id=bd4d72b23948df21 ip="invalid IP" udp=0 tcp=0

[/ALL]
Another problem, not sync
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 0,
  healedBytecodeBytes: 0,
  healedBytecodes: 0,
  healedTrienodeBytes: 0,
  healedTrienodes: 0,
  healingBytecode: 0,
  healingTrienodes: 0,
  highestBlock: 0,
  startingBlock: 0,
  syncedAccountBytes: 0,
  syncedAccounts: 0,
  syncedBytecodeBytes: 0,
  syncedBytecodes: 0,
  syncedStorage: 0,
  syncedStorageBytes: 0,
  txIndexFinishedBlocks: 0,
  txIndexRemainingBlocks: 1
}



admin.nodeInfo.enode of nodes give public addr against 127.0.0.1

My bessst regards

Ganache is going to be deactivated, instead use Hardhat
